# Obtaining room info from forge api

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative, forge, viewer

I need to get room information from the Revit model via Forge. I have tried to use generateMasterViews parameter as in this example;https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces. But , it did not work. How can I show the room details of the .rvt model in Model Browser of the viewer and get the room details by using model derivative's web service that is using for get metadata and properties? (Exporting nwc file and using it is not applicaple for me.)